# How to get the the node object or array from JSON based on excel sheet data using groovy?

Tags: json, api, groovy

Lets say I have the following JSON :-

```
{
  "book": [

  {
     "id": "01",
     "language": "Java",
     "edition": "third",
     "author": "Herbert Schildt"
  },

  {
     "id": "07",
     "language": "C++",
     "edition": "second",
     "author": "E.Balagurusamy"
  }

  ]
}
```

And, I am passing the value of author from excel sheet to check if that author is present or not. If that author is present inside JSON, then that that particular array node only and remove other from the JSON.

For Example:- I am passing "author" value as "Herbert Schildt" from excel sheet. Now this value is present inside JSON, So, I need this particular array node to be printed and rest all should be removed. Like this:-

```
{
"book": [
 {
 "id": "01",
 "language": "Java",
 "edition": "third",
 "author": "Herbert Schildt"
  }
]
}
```

Can it be done using groovy? I have tried with HashMap but couldn't get through.

Comment: read docs http://groovy-lang.org/json.html

Comment: something along the lines of `json.book = json.book.findAll{ it.author == 'Herber Schildt' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy using groovy:

```
def text = '''{
  "book": [

  {
     "id": "01",
     "language": "Java",
     "edition": "third",
     "author": "Herbert Schildt"
  },

  {
     "id": "07",
     "language": "C++",
     "edition": "second",
     "author": "E.Balagurusamy"
  }

  ]
}
'''

def result = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(
 [book: new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(text).book.findAll{it.author == "Herbert Schildt"}]
)

println result
```

Comment: What if, I am passing dynamic data from excel. We will have many array object with data as "id", "language", "edition" and "author". Then I will pass the author value from excel in one column only like this - Herbert Schildt#E.Balagurusamy#Korth Dery#Robin Ture. Then how will i do it.. Since it is dynamic now.

Comment: Do you need to output all books with one of them Herbert Schildt#E.Balagurusamy#Korth Dery#Robin Ture ? Then JsonSlurper().parseText(text).book.findAll{authorsString.tokenize('#').contains(it.author)}

Answer (score 0):

**You may try this ways json search**

```js
var json = '{"book":[{"id":"01","language":"Java","edition":"third","author":"Herbert Schildt"},{"id":"07","language":"C++","edition":"second","author":"E.Balagurusamy"}]}';
var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
var result = {};
result.book = [];
var author = "Herbert Schildt";
parsed.book.map((i, j) =>  {
 if(i.author == author) {
  
  result.book.push(i);
 }
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks Aman, This is in JavaScript , I guess. I need in groovy